# Recommendations for database structure with huge dataset

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design, data-warehouse

It seems to me this question will be without precise answer since requires too complex analysis and deep dive into details of our system.

We have distributed net of sensors. Information gathered in one database and futher processed.

Current DB design is to have one huge table partitioned per month. We try keep it at 1 billion (usually 600-800 million records), so fill rate is at 20-50 million records per day.

DB server currently is MS SQL 2008 R2 but we started from 2005 and upgrade during project development.

The table itself contains SensorId, MessageTypeId, ReceiveDate and Data field. Current solution is to preserve sensor data in Data field (binary, 16 byte fixed length) with partially decoding it's type and store it in messageTypeId.

We have different kind of message type sending by sensors (current is approx 200) and it can be futher increased on demand.

Main processing is done on application server which fetch records on demand (by type, sensorId and date range), decode it and carry out required processing. Current speed is enough for such amount of data.

We have request to increase capacity of our system in 10-20 times and we worry is our current solution is capable of that.

We have also 2 ideas to "optimise" structure which I want to discuss.

1 Sensor's data can be splitted into types, I'll use 2 primary one for simplicity: (value) level data (analog data with range of values), state data (fixed amount of values)

So we can redesign our table to bunch of small ones by using following rules:

- for each fixed type value (state type) create it's own table with SensorId and ReceiveDate (so we avoid store type and binary blob), all depended (extended) states will be stored in own table similar Foreign Key, so if we have `State` with values `A` and `B`, and depended (or additional) states for it `1` and `2` we ends with tables `StateA_1`, `StateA_2`, `StateB_1`, `StateB_2`. So table name consist of fixed states it represents.
- for each analog data we create seperate table it will be similar first type but cantains additional field with sensor value;

Pros:

- Store only required amount of data (currently our binary blob Data contains space to longest value) and reduced DB size;
- To get data of particular type we get access right table instead of filter by type;

Cons:

- AFAIK, it violates recommended  practices;
- Requires framework development to automate table management since it will be DBA's hell to maintain it manually;
- The amount of tables can be considerably large since requires full coverage of possible values;
- DB schema changes on introduction new sensor data or even new state value for already defined states thus can require complex change;
- Complex management leads to error prone;
- It maybe DB engine hell to insert values in such table orgranisation?
- DB structure is not fixed (constantly changed);

Probably all cons outweight a few pros but if we get significant performance gains and / or (less preferred but valuable too) storage space maybe we follow that way.

2 Maybe just split table per sensor (it will be about 100 000 tables) or better by sensor range and/or move to different databases with dedicated servers but we want avoid hardware span if it possible.

3 Leave as it is.

4 Switch to different kind of DBMS, e.g. column oriented DBMS (HBase and similar).

What do you think? Maybe you can suggest resource for futher reading?

**Update:**
The nature of system that some data from sensors can arrive even with month delay (usually 1-2 week delay), some always online, some kind of sensor has memory on-board and go online eventually. Each sensor message has associated event raised date and server received date, so we can distinguish recent data from gathered some time ago. The processing include some statistical calculation, param deviation detection, etc. We built aggregated reports for quick view, but when we get data from sensor updates old data (already processed) we have to rebuild some reports from scratch, since they depends on all available data and aggregated values can't be used. So we have usually keep 3 month data for quick access and other archived. We try hard to reduce needed to store data but decided that we need it all to keep results accurate.

**Update2:**

Here table with primary data. As I mention in comments we remove all dependencies and constrains from it during "need for speed", so it used for storage only.

```
CREATE TABLE [Messages](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sourceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [messageDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [serverDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [messageTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [data] [binary](16) NOT NULL
)
```

Sample data from one of servers:

```
id      sourceId    messageDate          serverDate messageTypeId   data
1591363304  54  2010-11-20 04:45:36.813 2010-11-20 04:45:39.813 257 0x00000000000000D2ED6F42DDA2F24100

1588602646  195 2010-11-19 10:07:21.247 2010-11-19 10:08:05.993 258 0x02C4ADFB080000CFD6AC00FBFBFBFB4D

1588607651  195 2010-11-19 10:09:43.150 2010-11-19 10:09:43.150 258 0x02E4AD1B280000CCD2A9001B1B1B1B77
```

Comment: Hi Nick. You only speak about the input data and storage ideas. Ideally, form follows function so the $1 million questions is: what are you doing with your data?  You'll get much better suggestions for reaching the goal you care about rather than ideas about storage that don't speak to your final goal.

Comment: Thank you for response, Sir Wobin. If describe in three words: we process it :) I update my question

Answer (score 1):

Just going to throw some ideas out there, hope they are useful - they're some of the things I'd be considering/thinking about/researching into.

**Partitioning** - you mention the table is partitioned by month. Is that manually partitioned yourself, or are you making use of the partitioning functionality available in Enterprise Edition? If manual, consider using the built in partitioning functionality to partition your data out more which should give you increased scalability / performance. This "[Partitioned Tables and Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)" article on MSDN by Kimberly Tripp is great - lot of great info in there, I won't do it a injustice by paraphrasing! Worth considering this over manually creating 1 table per sensor which could be more difficult to maintain/implement and therefore added complexity (simple = good). Of course, only if you have Enterprise Edition.

**Filtered Indexes** - check out [this MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)

There is of course the hardware element - goes without saying that a meaty server with oodles of RAM/fast disks etc will play a part.

Comment: Thank you for response. We use partitioning functionality available in Enterprise Edition. Thank you for links, I can't guess how we can use filtered indexes :( We already built clustered index to increase insert rate, and non-clustered to support each type of select we usually do or you suggest instead of come with split table into small ones, organize filtered indexes by using predicates to exctract fields from binary data and thus filter request by using DBMS engine and proper indexes. It can ends with bunch of indexes...

Answer (score 1):

One technique, not so much related to databases, is to switch to recording a change in values  -- with having minimum of n records per minute or so. So, for example if as sensor no 1 is sending something like:

```
Id  Date              Value
-----------------------------
1 2010-10-12 11:15:00 100
1 2010-10-12 11:15:02 100
1 2010-10-12 11:15:03 100
1 2010-10-12 11:15:04 105
```

then only first and last record would end in the DB. To make sure that the sensor is "live" minimum of 3 records would be entered per minute. This way the volume of data would be reduced.

Not sure if this helps, or if it would be feasible in your application -- just an idea.

**EDIT**

Is it possible to archive data based on the probability of access? Would it be correct to say that old data is less likely to be accessed than new data? If so, you may want to take a look at look at Bill Inmon's *DW 2.0 Architecture for The Next Generation of Data Warehousing* where he discusses model for moving data through different DW zones (Interactive, Integrated, Near-Line, Archival) based on the probability of access. Access times vary from very fast (Interactive zone) to very slow (Archival). Each zone has different hardware requirements. The objective is to prevent large amounts of data clogging the DW.

Comment: Nice idea. Reduces stored volume, but somehow doubles the recording processing, since you must read the latest measurement every time you get a new one.

Comment: @iDevelop, yes though, -- depending on number of sensors -- the last reading can be probably cached on the application level.

Comment: thank you. We already implemented such compression, on server side and client (sensor firmware). Usually sensor store new value on state change without store polled values. One exception is keep alive packets from online sensors but they not stored in DB.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at Bill Inmon's DW 2.0 Architecture for The Next Generation of Data Warehousing

Answer (score 1):

Storage-wise you are probably going to be fine. SQL Server will handle it.

What worries me is the load your server is going to take. If you are receiving transactions constantly, you would have some ~400 transactions per second today. Increase this by a factor of 20 and you are looking at ~8,000 transactions per second. That's not a small number considering you are doing reporting on the same data...

Btw, do I understand you correctly in that you are discarding the sensor data when you have processed it? So your total data set will be a "rolling" 1 billion rows? Or do you just append the data?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it worry us too. Current our implementation is to gather incoming data in-memory and form bulk insert operation based on time and/or amount of data received. This lower tps requirement. Also we implemented very memory efficient (we hope at least, it similar to structure I described in first option) cache so part of data (sometimes all data needed to build report) gets from cache instead DB. Also in memory cache stored at least last 2 weeks data and all new values so we try to avoid DB hit as we can. So we use DB to warm-up our cache during start and during "report" creation.

Comment: Also we use our cache instead DB itself to build all required processing. I thought maybe this design is not so good and we have to rely more on DBMS? Especially under heavy load.

Comment: @nick, I was going to suggest something along that line (collect and bulk) but much cruder, and you are already way ahead of me it seems :) If you could update your question with what you are doing with the data once it's in the database, we might be able to come up with more ideas. For now, I'm gonna back out, since I'm not experienced enough with SQL server to suggest anything else.

Comment: @Ronnis, thank you for suggestions and trying to help anyway. We tried in past different scenarios but ends with using DBMS as storage with additional services (convinient backup, replication, fault tolerance, etc.) with ability to select data in date range fast enough (with proper indexes). We try to make some preprocessing by using DBMS functions but all our attempts lead to unacceptable performance, so we take out all processing to application server.

Comment: @nick, hmm. Would you mind sharing the actual DDL for this table along with an example of that binary data you store?

Comment: @Ronnis, I updated my question. But I don't think it really helps without internal knowledge kind of data received, how it processed and so on, but maybe you can suggest something. I very much appreciate your trying yo help, thank you.

Comment: @Nick, do your queries involve unpacking the binary data? And does it contain measures only, or also code/type information? I'm thinking you could "unpack" the data into columns to enable set based processing of your data. Or the type of sensor data is different enough to make it unrealistic? I'm unsure if SqlServer table compression works the same as in Oracle, but if it does, you might get away with only a minor increase in storage. What kind of reporting do you do? Would it be possible to satisfy the reporting need from aggregates only?

Comment: @Ronnis, queries only returns data field and can involve filtering by `sourceId`, `messageDate`, `serverDate`, `messageTypeId` but not by `data` itself. `data` field contains measures and states. We often enough introduce new message types for new type of sensors or maybe states/measures they send. If we "unpack" data to columns we'll end with approx 400-500 columns (if I understand correctly) most of them will be not used since sensors data for different message types not duplicated and introduce constant DB schema changes when need to include new message type processing

Comment: As I mention in my first Update section we can't find way to build reports from aggregates only. The main problem is accurate requirements. To demonstrate I'll project our real processing to simple example. Let say we have mobile sensor reporting its geographical coords. And we need to report what total path he moved already. Sensor can report its data in varying order (it depends on environment really). So let's say mobile sensor send to server coords, then can't send coords for 1 hour, send new coords and part of old from memory, another pause for 1 hour.

Comment: Server get say 1 coord, then another since 1 hour, so when calculating distance it can get simple vector length (a bit more complex really but not matters for example) between two points. After some time missed coords arrives, and total path can become significantly longer since now it consists of line parts each can be not aligned on original vector. Hope this example demostrate main problem...

Comment: Of course, we have aggregated reports but by convention only 3 month old data we can treat as static (thats why in particular we have 3 month archive rotation)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the datetime stamps as integers. I believe datetime stamps use 8 bytes and integers only use 4 within SQL. You'd have to leave off the year, but since you are partitioning by month it might not be a problem.

So '12/25/2010 23:22:59' would get stored as 1225232259 -MMDDHHMMSS

Just a thought...